# Ending a Loop only after a user input gives a yes - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create an app to take orders for a Hamburger and add additions. I want the additions to the burger to be based on a scanner input, but I am getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found". Would appreciate if someone could help me understand where am I going wrong. I am a newbie to Java so please bear with me.

My code:

```
public class Hamburger {

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String breadRoll;
    private String meat;


    private String addition1Name;
    private double addition1Price;

    private String addition2Name;
    private double addition2Price;

    private String addition3Name;
    private double addition3Price;

    private String addition4Name;
    private double addition4Price;


    public Hamburger(double price, String meat) {
        this.name = "Basic Hamburger";
        this.price = price;
        this.breadRoll = "White Bread";
        this.meat = meat;
    }

    public void checkingAdditionCount(){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Do you want to add more items?");
        String answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        boolean isCont = true;

        while (isCont && scanner.hasNextLine()){
            if (answer.equals("y")){
                additions();

            } else if (answer.equals("n")){
                addAllItemsAndBill();
                isCont = false;
                scanner.close();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter valid choice");
                additions();
            }
        }




    public void addAllItemsAndBill() {
        System.out.println("Your total bill amount is " + this.price);

    }

    public void additions(){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++){

            System.out.println("Enter the addition name: ");
            String additionName = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the addition price: ");
            if (scanner.hasNextDouble()){
                double additionPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
                this.price += additionPrice;
            }
            scanner.nextLine();
            checkingAdditionCount();

        }
        scanner.close();

        this.addition1Name = name;
        this.addition1Price = price;

    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getBreadRoll() {
        return breadRoll;
    }

    public void setBreadRoll(String breadRoll) {
        this.breadRoll = breadRoll;
    }

    public String getMeat() {
        return meat;
    }

    public void setMeat(String meat) {
        this.meat = meat;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to update `answer` **in** your loop.

Comment: Hello. checkingAdditionCount() is calling additions(), and additions() is calling checkingAdditionCount(). You shouldn't do that. It does not causes the error, but you should really avoid that. Moreover, checkingAdditionCount() and additions() are both creating different scanners and closing them. You should also avoid that. One scanner only would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code, like:

```java
while(true) {
  if(scanner.nextLine().equals("y")) break;
}
```

It will be looping until user input not equal 'y' :)

Comment: Thanks! I also want to end the loop only if the cashier enters a ‘n’ for a choice

Comment: Add ```String answer``` variable into this loop, which equals ```scanner.nextLine()``` and change ```if``` statement with ```if (answer.equals ("y") || answer.equals ("n")) break;``` If I understood everything correctly :D